# Class<T> will also do type erase at runtime, without type information how can reflection work?

Tags: java, reflection

```
public <T> T genericMethod(Class<T> tClass)throws InstantiationException ,
  IllegalAccessException{
        T instance = tClass.newInstance();
        return instance;
}

Object obj = genericMethod(Class.forName("com.test.YourClass"));
```

This is a typical code for java to use generic method return an instance of specific class.
Instance of Class is pass as an variable and new instance is created by calling the constructor through reflection.

I am still confused by the mechanism of reflection and Class class.
My question is, if the class information of YourClass will be erase from the Class
instance, when calling the reflection method, why it can create an YourClass but not an object?
Shouldn't an Object be created?

Comment: Type erasure erases the type parameters (those things in `<>`), not what's stored in the `Class` objects at runtime

Comment: That's like saying, if I added some strings to a `List<String>`, but it gets erased to `List`, those strings I added will all somehow get "erased" and become instances of `Object`s!

Comment: Two more question: what kind of information and where does the information exactly stored in the object of Class<T>.  Is an instance of Class<String> a singleton. It seems all object of Class<String> are the same.

Comment: The OpenJDK [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java) of `Class<T>` can serve as a reference. You can see what fields it has. Instances of `Class<T>` are considered equal, if they represent the same class, and are loaded by the same class loader. In theory, there could be different instances of `Class<String>` if they are loaded by different class loaders.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I will learn it.

Answer (score 1):

`Class<T>` is a special type where the *instances* of that type that actually hold information about `T`, and the runtime can obtain the type information from the *instance*. But that's the only type that does so! For any other type, e.g. `List<T>`, instances of the type do *not* have any knowledge about `T` (because the purpose of `List` is different: to contain a sequence of objects of any type - the restriction that it only can hold `T` is enforced by the compiler but not by the runtime). In those situations, the instance can't tell the runtime anything useful about `T`.

"Type erasure" refers to the fact that the generic type parameter is erased from the *instance's type* during compilation, so a value that in the source code appears as `List<T>` appears as just `List` at runtime. The same holds for `Class<T>`, which appears as `Class` at runtime, but again, the instance itself knows what class `T` is because that's one of the purposes of the `Class` type.

---

Generics in Java is a huge hack that - quite impressively - they managed to implement only in the compiler. You can circumvent the compiler's checks by using reflection: for example, you could reflectively call `add(x)` on a `List<String> strings` where `x` is an `Integer`, and it will work because the instance is actually just a `List` that will accept values of any type. So now you have a `List<String>` where one element is an `Integer`! When you later try to do `strings.get(i)` (where `i` is the index you added the integer at), the implicit type cast to `String` that is inserted by the compiler is going to blow up.

Comment: Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(“com.test.YourClass”) method can return an Class<?> object. Is my understanding below correct: while ClassLoader loaded my class, binary code of my class where be stored somewhere in the JVM. clazz, the instance returned, refers to this loaded class.